C++ threads - async takes almost the same time to execute
As a novice in C++ threads, I am a little bit confused. The std::async, for 1024 function calls, has almost the same duration like the 1024 calls of the same function. My intention is to demostrate (at least for me) that, by using threads, the execution of the 1024 add function, takes less time. Here is my code
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

struct Timer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start, end;
    std::chrono::duration<float> duration{};
    Timer() {
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    ~Timer() {
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        duration = end - start;
        printf("Duration %f s\n", duration.count());
    }
};

int add(int a, int b) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <n>\n    where n is 0 or 1\n\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    Timer timer;
    if(atoi(argv[1]) == 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
            add(i, 1024);
        }
    }
    if(atoi(argv[1]) == 1) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
            std::future<int> result = std::async(std::launch::async, add, i, 1024);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

and the CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(threads)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(threads main.cpp)

A have tested the two scenarios and these are the durations:
cmake-build-debug\threads.exe 0    <---- 1024 calls of add in a for loop
Duration 16.136204 s

cmake-build-debug\threads.exe 1    <---- 1024 threads of add in a for loop
Duration 16.129925 s

What is wrong with my code and/or my logic?
SK

To elaborate on the comment by @AhmedAEK, what's happening is that the destructor for result blocks until the newly created thread finishes, so the code is simply running the entire function each time through the loop; there's no parallelism here. You don't benefit from spinning out a new thread unless the creating thread has something to do while the new thread is running.

Save the futures created in a loop in a container (vector) to prevent blocking. On the other note, your system probably doesn't have 1024 cores, so it's (heavily) oversubscribed, due to heavy context switching you might not see much of improvements. Also you are not using the result of add function, so I wonder if compiler can optimize away the whole loop as a noop.

PeteBecker, Gene:
Man, what you said is correct and helped me! As I said, I am stil a novice. Obviously, I did not read the complete reference of the std::future and others, too. The fact that I am storing the std::future objects into a vector, skips the destructor calls for each future object until the vector is destroyed. This happens after all 1024 threads are terminated. By doing this it runs much faster and takes in avarage 1.056349 seconds. My laptop has 16 cores, but even so the difference is significant.

Side note: Be careful with high_resolution_clock. It is specified to favour resolution over clock stability, so it's allowed to do stuff, like going backward in time, that makes an absolute mess of timing. At the very least you need to use the is_steady function to confirm time won't jump around on you, but if is_steady returns  false, then what?  Have another code branch that uses steady_clock? In the vast majority of cases, you'd be better off using steady_clock directly for timing.

As a beginner of threads, be aware that every thread you create has a creation overhead and a maintenance overhead.  Worst case, your thread uses the same core as your main program and the OS swaps them out.  For this reason, don't create more threads than you have cores.  Also, the OS is in charge of delegating the execution of your threads.  Check with your OS to see if you can delegate your threads to cores and have them exclusive on those cores.  For best efficiency, your threads should execute longer than the overhead times.

@ThomasMatthews std::async is probably using some kind of thread pool so should have less overhead

@AlanBirtles That was the intention but AFAIK no implementation does. Each async function call must behave as-if started on a new thread. A thread pool causes problems with thread_local, they aren't created or destroyed between calls which can cause the balehaviour to be different from running on a new thread.
